# Object create not found error in oracle toad

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, toad

I am creating procedure in oracle toad. When I run this procedure I am getting error like "object create not found. Am new to oracle.

```
procedure
---------
CREATE PROCEDURE CISCOCUIC.insrtCDRdet(rec integer)
IS   
 BEGIN
  insert into CISCOCUIC.CISCOCCDR_TBL(FLD_CDRRECORDTYPE)values(rec);
  COMMIT;
 END;
/
```

When I press alt+enter key am getting error object create not found

Answer (score 1):

Create your procedure as below, provided you have the privileges to CREATE procedures in CISCOCUIC schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CISCOCUIC.insrtcdrdet (rec INTEGER)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CISCOCUIC.ciscoccdr_tbl (fld_cdrrecordtype)
      VALUES   (rec
                  );

    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

alt enter in TOAD means describe. if you had the cursor on CREATE at the time, it would give you that error. instead just hit F9 to run that script in.